# Interpolation of the values of points on the surface created by convex hull

Tags: matlab, interpolation, convex-hull

I have some 3D points like [x,y,z] and their values like [Bx,By,Bz] . The convex hull of these points are generated by [`convhull`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) or [`convexHull`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation.convexhull.html)

[image: convex hull]

Now I want to interpolate the values of triangle vertices for N new points on the convex hull. What are the possible methods to do this?

Comment: What do you mean interpolate the values of triagle vertices? Of the complex hull?

Comment: yes, each vertex point has a value. They must be interpolated for new points on the generated convex hull.

Comment: Right. So if you use `convhull` for example, it returns the triangulation.You just need to know how to get values in a 3D triangle, which is quite easy (hint: its just values on a surface, bounded by some limits)

Comment: Where the new points are placed? Inside ,outside or on the surface of the convex hull? What Interpolation method do you want to use? Should the interpolation method use just 3 vertices , 4 vertices  or all of the vertices of the convex hull ?

Comment: The new point must be on the surface of the convex hull. The interpolation must be applied for each triangle (3 vertices of each triangle of the convex hull).

Comment: If I correctly understand you want to generate random points on the surface of the convex hull and interpolate their values based on the vertices of the convex hull.

Comment: yes exactly....But notice that, it must be done for each triangle on the convex hull.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a given point is `p=(x,y,z)` and you have found that it's located in a triangle `p1=(x1, y1, z1)`, `p2=(x2, y2, z2)`, and `p3=(x3, y3, z3)` (on the convex hull). Now if I understand correctly, we want to compute three non-negative real-valued `a`, `b`, and `c`, such that `a * p1 + b * p2 + c * p3 = p` and `a + b + c = 1` (linear combination of the triangle's vertices). It can be defined by a matrix like `M = [p1;p2;p3]` with an equation like `[a b c] * M = p`. Hence, `[a b c] = p * inv(M)`. You can do it for all other points.

Notice that if `p` is not inside the triangle, the solved `[a b c]` will not satisfy the non-negativity or `a + b + c = 1`.